# Azure Function prevent loading functions from third party assemblies

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swashbuckle

I have an azure function (V3) app that uses some functions from a third-party assembly, brought in (in this case) by an other project reference (but could also be another nuget).

When I start the Azure function app, it not only auto discovers the functions in my own project, but also those in the third party assembly. Apparently it scans every DLL in the bin folder.

How can I control from which assemblies are "scanned" for azure function attributes?
Or put another way how can I make sure only my App is scanned for functions with the functionAttribute?

Assume I don't have the option to adjust the third-party code.

edit:
because people asked some basic code. The functions in "AzureFunctions.Frontend.dll are hosted in a azure function app that requires authentication. I want to split off the swagger documentation generation to an anonymouse freely accesible azure function app.
When Including AzureFunctions.Frontend.dll as an project dependency so I can load it from the bin directory It also discovers and runs the function in AzureFunctions.Frontend.dll. I just want the dll included to load it to generate documentation only.
The second Assembly load line does that by going outside the swagger project folder. That provides the desired result but is useless when deploying the app to the cloud.

```cs
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle;
using AzureFunctions.Swagger;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;
using System.Reflection;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices((hostBuilderContext, services) => ConfigureServices(hostBuilderContext, services))
    .Build();

host.Run();

void ConfigureServices(HostBuilderContext hostBuilderContext, IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Assembly functionAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "AzureFunctions.Frontend.dll"));
    
    Assembly functionAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"<outsideprojectlocation>\AzureFunctions.Frontend\bin\Debug\net6.0\AzureFunctions.Frontend.dll");
    
    services.AddSwashBuckle(functionAssembly, opts => Swagger.ConfigureSwaggerDocOptions(opts));
}
```

swagger.cs

```cs
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle.Attribute;
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AzureFunctions.Extensions.Swashbuckle.Settings;
using Microsoft.OpenApi;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AzureFunctions.Swagger
{
    public class Swagger
    {
        private readonly ISwashBuckleClient _swashBuckleClient;

        public Swagger(ISwashBuckleClient swashBuckleClient)
        {
            _swashBuckleClient = swashBuckleClient;

        }

        [SwaggerIgnore]
        [Function("SwaggerJson")]
        public HttpResponseData SwaggerJson([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "swagger/json")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            return _swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerJsonDocumentResponse(req);
        }

        [SwaggerIgnore]
        [Function("SwaggerUI")]
        public HttpResponseData SwaggerUi([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "GET", Route = "swagger/ui")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext)
        {
            return _swashBuckleClient.CreateSwaggerUIResponse(req, "swagger/json");
        }

        internal static void ConfigureSwaggerDocOptions(SwaggerDocOptions opts)
        {
            opts.SpecVersion = OpenApiSpecVersion.OpenApi3_0;
            opts.AddCodeParameter = true;
            opts.PrependOperationWithRoutePrefix = true;
            opts.XmlPath = "TestFunction.xml";
            opts.Documents = new[]
            {
                    new SwaggerDocument
                    {
                        Name = "v1",
                        Title = "API",
                        Description = "API",
                        Version = "v1"
                    },
                    new SwaggerDocument
                    {
                        Name = "v2",
                        Title = "API",
                        Description = "API",
                        Version = "v2"
                    }
                };
            opts.Title = "API";

            opts.ConfigureSwaggerGen = x =>
            {
                //custom operation example
                x.CustomOperationIds(apiDesc => apiDesc.TryGetMethodInfo(out MethodInfo methodInfo)
                    ? methodInfo.GetCustomAttribute<FunctionAttribute>().Name
                    : new Guid().ToString());
                x.CustomSchemaIds(c => c.FullName);

                x.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2,
                    Flows = new OpenApiOAuthFlows
                    {
                        Implicit = new OpenApiOAuthFlow
                        {
                            AuthorizationUrl = new Uri("https://your.idserver.net/connect/authorize"),
                            Scopes = new Dictionary<string, string>
                            {
                                    { "api.read", "Access read operations" },
                                    { "api.write", "Access write operations" }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            };

            // set up your client ID if your API is protected
            opts.ClientId = "your.client.id";
            opts.OAuth2RedirectPath = "http://localhost:7071/api/swagger/oauth2-redirect";

        }
    }
}
```

edit2:

I found a partial answer. If I link the external dll's to a subfolder of the project I can load them for swashbuckle to create documentation. The Azure functions runtime does not seem to check for dlls with function attributes in subfolders.
However I much rather have the third party dll included via the a nuget or project reference as that way its easier to keep up to date.

Comment: Please show us your startup class or `Program.cs`.

Comment: If you don't have them, I'm pretty sure you will need them. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/quickstart-azure-functions-csharp?tabs=in-process) you can see how to add them to your function project.